# Appending html Tag with regex

Tags: php, regex

I would like to change a string from:

```
<a href....>*</a>
```

to:

```
<article><a href=....>*</a></article>
```

I have tried this but my understanding of RegEx is too bad.

```
$n = '/<a (.*)[^>]>/';
$h = '/<article><a(.*)[^>]>/i','/<\/a></articla>/';
$reg = preg_replace($n, $h, $content);
```

Comment: For variable $h, ending tag </articla> should be </article>

Comment: Firstly, you have a typo. Secondly, "_my understanding of RegEx is to bad....._" Then don't use regex, use a parser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3182500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution would match <a href...> but not the closing element.

Try this:

```
$n = '/(<a [^>]*>([^<]*<(\/[^a])|[^\/])*\/a>)/i';
$h = '<article>${1}</article>';
$reg = preg_replace($n, $h, $content);
```

**Edit:**

now respects child elements

Explenation:

```
<a [^>]*>
```

Matches the start tag.

```
(
[^<]*<
```

Finds the next tag.

```
(\/[^a])|[^\/]
)*
```

Ensures, that the next tag is not a closing </a> and so matches every other tag.

```
\/a>
```

Matches the closing </a>, finally. (Note: the < has already been matched).

Comment: Hi, this is 99% of what I searched;) but what if an other tag is inside my anchor.

Comment: @user1606423 improved my answer

Answer (score 0):

if `$content` is just a "string" and not html, then just go for the simple way:

```
$content = str_replace('</a>','</a></article>',str_replace('<a href=','<article><a href=',$content));
```

Simple, clean, no need for regex.

If `$content` is NOT just a "string" but it is html, **then nor str_replace, nor regex will help.** You will need a html parser.